# Несколько сообщений за раз consumer

Tags: rabbitmq

Смотрю насколько мне под задачу подходит RabbitMQ.

Код из примера

```
    $consumerTag = gethostname() . '_' . getmypid();
    $connection = $this->getConnection();
    $channel = $this->getChannel();
    $channel->basic_qos(null, 1, null);
    $channel->queue_bind(self::QUEUE_NAME, 'exchange');
    $channel->basic_consume(self::QUEUE_NAME, $consumerTag, false, true, false, false, function($msg) {
        echo $msg->body, "\n";
        sleep(2);
    });

    while(count($channel->callbacks)) {
        echo time()."\r\n";
        $channel->wait();
    }
```

Возможно в callback'e получить несколько сообщений из очереди? Возможно это вообще противоречит идеологии RabbitMQ?

Comment: callback наверняка вызывается для каждой мессаги отдельно. но это же не может быть преградой для героя

Comment: @Sergey, все так =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался, для получения следующего сообщения без ожидания можно воспользоваться

```
$channel->basic_get(self::QUEUE_NAME)
```